# Maintaining timestamp sequence of incoming streaming data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

So I am pushing some json data from kafka to Spark using structured streaming. The data, in form of dictionary, has a field "timestamp". After parsing json and getting individual columns for every key, I noticed the timestamp field is not in the sequence in which it was pushed to kafka cluster i.e.

```
+----------+
| Timestamp|
+----------+
|     1    |
|     2    |
|     6    |  <--
|     4    |
|     5    |
|     7    |  <--
+----------+
```

Is there any way to make sure that the data remains in sequence? One thing I can think of is using orderby on timestamp with output_mode="complete". Are there any other efficient alternatives?
Thanks.

Comment: Kafka doesn't order by time, only within partitions... How many partitions does your topic have? Are you viewing multiple partitions at once here? Your only option is order within Spark, assuming you really need to

Comment: Don't know how many partitions but it is left on default configs. Could you please direct me to any spark example of ordering in structured streaming in python?

Comment: I could link you to the pyspark sql orderby function, but I trust that you can find that yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka guarantee messages order within partition only. If you want strict order within Kafka - keep one partition per topic and guarantee ordering when delivering there. You might want to implement "ordering service" which reads from the incoming queue and writes messages to another queue with only one partition. Good explanation and examples may be found in various blog posts: [here](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/blog/2018-08-21-faq-apache-kafka-strict-ordering.html) or [here](https://medium.com/@felipedutratine/kafka-ordering-guarantees-99320db8f87f) and more.

Ordering messages in Spark is the easiest option. You should consider saving or caching ordered results to storage for reuse.

Comment: What output mode do I need to use if I am ordering in spark? Also, will the orderby will work on the entire data (including cached) or only on the received batches?

Comment: That really depends on what are you doing with the data after the sink. I'd probably go for architecture where ordered data storred to storage (let's say once a minute or hour) and then streamed with another job in ordered chunks of minute or hour